# Datetimepicker : recreate datetimepicker element on certain condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I came across a use-case where based on user selection (onChange) the `datetimepicker` should change. i.e. it's minDate, default date. But I do not find any way to do it and conclusion is once the `detetimepicker` is initialized or defined, it's options can not be redefined.

e.g.
    //currentDate some date

```
var relativeDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),     currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    $('#expiryDateTime').datetimepicker({minDate: relativeDate, format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'});

if(condition_1)
{
var relativeDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    $('#expiryDateTime').datetimepicker({minDate: relativeDate, format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'});
}
else
if(condition_2)
{
var relativeDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth() + 6, currentDate.getDate());
    $('#expiryDateTime').datetimepicker({minDate: relativeDate, format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'});
}
```

and so on..

But the `detetimepicker` does not change.

Comment: Did you try using the .live function of jquery on onchange method and reintializing the datepicker in that?

Comment: Hey Moax6629, first of I don't have any issues on catching the event of change but the core issue reinitialize the datetimepicker element. 
And to your suggestion to use .live() i recommend you to not use it as it is depreciated and not encouraged to use. Instead use .on() of jquery.

Comment: Can you link the datepicker you are using?

Comment: I am using this datetimepicker plugin.

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37